# Ordering by multiple columns in mysql with subquery

Tags: mysql

Hey guys I have a query that selects data and organizes but not in the correct order. What I want to do is select all the comments for a user in that week and sort it by each topic, then sort the cluster by the latest timestamp of each comment in their respective cluster. My current query selects the right data, but in seemingly random order. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
    select * from (
      SELECT
        topic.topic_title, topic.topic_id
      FROM comments
      JOIN topic ON topic.topic_id=comments.topic_id
      WHERE comments.user='$user' AND comments.timestamp>$week order by comments.timestamp desc) derived_table
group by topic_id
```

Comment: PS cluster and sort=group, and sorry for the stupid title, I was having technical problems submitting when I used the word group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Final version, I hope:

```
SELECT topic_title, topic_id
      FROM comments
      JOIN topic ON topic.topic_id = comments.topic_id
      WHERE comments.user = '$user' AND comments.timestamp > $week
      GROUP BY topic_id ORDER BY MAX(timestamp) DESC
```

MAX(timestamp) will be applied to each grouping individually (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply mike, first of all, just to clarify, I want to select all the topic contents from the topic table for each group. Basically I want to find all the comments that were made in the past week and group them by their topic so I can get the topic information for each group, therefore getting the information for all the latest active topics. Your query, got the information for one of the topics several times. My original got the information for the correct topics, but not in the correct order. Hopefully that is a little clearer.

Comment: Essentially I just want to get the information for all the topics that have been active within a week, determined by their latest comment's timestamp.

Comment: If I had read more carefully, I would have noticed that you mentioned that your query already pulls out the correct data, but not in the correct order.  Keeping that in mind, it's much easier to understand the problem.  Let me know if this iteration helps (I've never edited an answer so much before!  ;o)

Comment: Thanks a lot mike, appreciate the article reference and explanation as well. Your query worked. Appreciate your time ++points.

Comment: Looking one more time, I realized that you don't need the sub-query any longer, so one last edit...

Answer (score 1):

ORDER by topic.tropic_title, comments.timestamp

Comment: btw, order-by clause goes after group-by clause.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, when I move the order by out of the sub query like so, group by topic_id order by comments.timestamp desc without even changing it like you said, I get no results.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other comments you need to move `ORDER BY topic.topic_title` out of the subquery.

Comment: When I do that for some reason I immediately get no results. When I leave it in, I get the desired results, but in scrambled order.

Comment: In another comment you say you moved the `group by topic_id` out as well.  You should leave that in the subquery.  That is not part of the ORDER BY clause.  I am only talking about `ORDER BY topic.topic_title`

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but I don't think your query returns **all the comments** for the topic.  Since you're grouping by the topic_id, it's going to collapse it by topic and return just one row and comment per topic.  If you want all the comments for each topic sorted by topic and timestamp, you can use this query.

```
SELECT topic.topic_title,topic.topic_id,comments.*
  FROM comments
  JOIN topic ON topic.topic_id=comments.topic_id
  WHERE comments.user='$user' 
  AND comments.timestamp>$week 
ORDER by topic.topic_title,comments.timestamp desc
```

If what you're trying to do is group by the topic and return the latest comment for each topic, then you can use the following query.  The query gets the latest comment for each topic and grabs for each topic the entire comments row matching that latest timestamp.

```
SELECT latest_ts.topic_title,latest_ts.topic_id,comments.*
  FROM comments
  JOIN (SELECT topic.topic_title,topic.topic_id,max(comments.timestamp) latest_timestamp
     FROM comments
     JOIN topic ON topic.topic_id=comments.topic_id
     WHERE comments.user=$user 
     AND comments.timestamp>$week
     GROUP BY topic.topic_title,topic.topic_title) latest_ts
  ON latest_ts.latest_timestamp = comments.timestamp
  AND latest_ts.topic_id = comments.topic_id
ORDER by latest_ts.topic_title
```

The query above could return two rows per topic in the unlikely event that the last two comments for a given topic have the same timestamp.  If this is a concern, you will need to do a little extra work wrapping this output in another round of grouping to lose the unneeded rows.

Comment: funny you should suggest that, I did in face need that functionality, so I was trying to modify mike's query and I saw yours. I tried it and it does not return any information, the query is not valid. Thanks anyway nefsu. If you discover the error before me, let me know.

Comment: I've fixed and tested the query on comments and topic tables.  Two comments  (1) My query assumes that your comments table has a column called comment_id  (2) It's generally good practice to names your tables in the plural (topics instead of topic..like you did with comments)

Comment: I am not sure how you are testing it but I consistently get 0 results returned because the query is undefined. What is latest_ts?

Comment: mikes query works for organizing the topics by latest comment for each topic, the problem is it just returns random comments for each ordered topic, can it not be modified to return the latest comment with a subquery?